# SQL Server не существует или доступ запрещен

Tags: sql-server

Выскакивает такая ошибка при подключении к базе через ADOConnection к sql server:

> [DBNETLIB] ConnectionOpen (Connected()). SQL Server не существует или доступ запрещен

Comment: Очевидно же: отлаживать приложение, искать ошибку, устранять. Вы на какой стадии?

Comment: Если речь об SQL Server, то почему указан тэг `mysql`?

Comment: все готово я взял у человека установил sql server но не могу подключится

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть вот этот [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/467554/179270) и ссылки там фигурирующие.